# xsl variable check in select

Tags: xml, xslt

I am retriving a variable from param as

```
<xsl:param name="app"/>
```

I want to check if the $app is equal to the name. XML looks like this

```
<application>
 <name>myapp</name>
<detail>
<xyz>0</xyz>
</detail>
</application>
```

There are going to be multiple applications so I want to check the name and select xyz.
Currently I am doing the following

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="//application[name=$app]/detail/xyz"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is as name=abc; how to make it check as name='abc'?

Comment: So which XSLT processor do you use, which interface or API to set that parameter? In what way does your code fail? The syntax `//application[name=$app]` seems right to me to compare the `name` element to the parameter value.

Comment: I don't know about the xslt processor but for testing purposes instead of param I was using variable so when I use <xsl-variable select="abc" it is not working but after making it select=" 'abc' " the code is working.

Comment: Well, `<xsl:param name="app" select="'abc'"/>` is the right way to test to have the variable bound to a string value. If you use `select="abc"` then you test something completely different, namely you select any element named `abc` of the context node where you have the `xsl:param` or `xsl:variable` declaration.

Comment: What I am trying to do is get app name from link as /myfile.xsl?app=abc and store it in `xsl:param name="app"` so now how to check it?

Comment: It depends entirely on the framework or programming language where you process that URL/link with the query string and of course of the API of the XSLT processor you use. You haven't given any information on that.

Comment: I am using nginx the param is passed to the link using nginx conf to the .xsl file

Comment: Okay so on github this is suggested by the user **you'll need libxml2 and libxslt1.1** trying it